# Information on Simple Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm supposed to give a presentation on Simple Groups for my Abstract Algebra I class (we've covered basic group theory). Is there any topic within Simple Groups that could offer enough material for 15-20 mins of talking/presenting? I was thinking about showing how to construct a simple group or how to find them, but I really don't know where to look to get information on that.

Any ideas for a topic of presentation or resources for more information on simple groups?

Thanks

Comment: The relations between simple groups and prime numbers? The classification?

Comment: Perhaps how to prove groups are _not_ simple? Some basic applications of Sylow, or maybe Burnside's theorem, which rules out tons of groups. Or talk about families of simple groups, such as $A_n$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$, or $PSL_n(F)$, and how there are 26 that aren't in a family.